# Sqlalchemy select statement with order_by and distinct fails but session.query with same clauses works

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am running Sqlalchemy 1.4.28 my with MySQL 8.0.19 and trying to fetch some data after joining multiple tables and then performing `order_by` and `distinct` on the result set.

I am encountering a problem where the operation using `session.query` interface works just fine without any errors however when I use native `select` directly with `session.execute` the query fails with `3065, "Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'my_db.fault.jira_ticket' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT")`.

### Using `session.query`

```py
sess.query(CM, CM.cm_id).where(CM.status == "created").join(Fault).join(NewFaultMap).order_by(Fault.jira_ticket).distinct().limit(1).all()


sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT DISTINCT cm.id AS cm_id, cm.created AS cm_created, cm.updated AS cm_updated, cm.status AS cm_status, cm.created_by AS cm_created_by, cm.updated_by AS cm_updated_by, cm.id AS cm_id__1, fault.jira_ticket AS fault_jira_ticket 
FROM cm INNER JOIN fault ON cm.id = fault.cm_id INNER JOIN faultmap ON faultmap.check_id = fault.check_id 
WHERE cm.status = %(status_1)s ORDER BY fault.jira_ticket 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - [cached since 3638s ago] {'status_1': 'created', 'param_1': 1}
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT fault.cm_id AS fault_cm_id, fault.created AS fault_created, fault.updated AS fault_updated, fault.id AS fault_id, fault.check_id AS fault_check_id, fault.jira_ticket AS fault_jira_ticket
FROM fault 
WHERE fault.cm_id IN (%(primary_keys_1)s)
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - [cached since 4814s ago] {'primary_keys_1': 2184184}
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT fault_1.id AS fault_1_id, faultmap.created AS faultmap_created, faultmap.updated AS faultmap_updated, faultmap.id AS faultmap_id, faultmap.check_id AS faultmap_check_id
FROM fault AS fault_1 INNER JOIN faultmap ON faultmap.check_id = fault_1.check_id 
WHERE fault_1.id IN (%(primary_keys_1)s)
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - [cached since 4814s ago] {'primary_keys_1': 556542}
```

### Using native `select`

```py
sess.execute(select(CM, CM.cm_id).where(CM.status == "created").join(Fault).join(NewFaultMap).order_by(Fault.jira_ticket).distinct().limit(1)).all()


OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (3065, "Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'my_db.fault.jira_ticket' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT")
[SQL: SELECT DISTINCT cm.id, cm.created, cm.updated, cm.status, cm.created_by, cm.updated_by, cm.id AS id__1 
FROM cm INNER JOIN fault ON cm.id = fault.cm_id INNER JOIN faultmap ON faultmap.check_id = fault.check_id 
WHERE cm.status = %(status_1)s ORDER BY fault.jira_ticket 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'status_1': 'created', 'param_1': 1}]
```

I see that `query` interface automatically adds the column in the `order_by` clause to the `select` list which the `select` statement does not do. So if I add the `order_by` field explicitly to the query using `select` it works & generates the following raw sql which matches exactly to the sql generated by `session.query` and running both the sqls directly on mysql gives same number of rows.

```
sess.execute(select(CM, CM.cm_id, Fault.jira_ticket).where(CM.status == "created").join(Fault).join(NewFaultMap).order_by(Fault.jira_ticket).distinct()).scalars().all()

sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT DISTINCT cm.id, cm.created, cm.updated, cm.status, cm.created_by, cm.updated_by, cm.id AS id__1, fault.jira_ticket 
FROM cm INNER JOIN fault ON cm.id = fault.cm_id INNER JOIN faultmap ON faultmap.check_id = fault.check_id 
WHERE cm.status = %(status_1)s ORDER BY fault.jira_ticket 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - [cached since 2090s ago] {'status_1': 'created', 'param_1': 1}
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT fault.cm_id AS fault_cm_id, fault.created AS fault_created, fault.updated AS fault_updated, fault.id AS fault_id, fault.check_id AS fault_check_id, fault.jira_ticket AS fault_jira_ticket
FROM fault 
WHERE fault.cm_id IN (%(primary_keys_1)s)
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - [cached since 4946s ago] {'primary_keys_1': 2184184}
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT fault_1.id AS fault_1_id, faultmap.created AS faultmap_created, faultmap.updated AS faultmap_updated, faultmap.id AS faultmap_id, faultmap.check_id AS faultmap_check_id
FROM fault AS fault_1 INNER JOIN faultmap ON faultmap.check_id = fault_1.check_id 
WHERE fault_1.id IN (%(primary_keys_1)s)
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - [cached since 4946s ago] {'primary_keys_1': 556542}
```

However on the python side I see the difference in number of result items

```py
len(sess.query(CM, CM.cm_id).where(CM.status == "created").join(Fault).join(NewFaultMap).order_by(Fault.jira_ticket).distinct().all())
Out[82]: 164

len(sess.execute(select(CM, CM.cm_id, Fault.jira_ticket).where(CM.status == "created").join(Fault).join(NewFaultMap).order_by(Fault.jira_ticket).distinct()).scalars().all())
Out[77]: 167
```

This is how the models for these tables look

```py
class CustomBase(Timestamp):
    """
    Custom base class which will add
    created and updated fields automatically to the newly created table
    __repr__ method
    """

    def as_dict(self):
        return {k: v for k, v in vars(self).items() if not k.startswith("_sa")}


CustomModelBase: Any = declarative_base(cls=CustomBase)


class NewFaultMap(CustomModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "faultmap"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    check_id = Column(String(96), unique=True, nullable=False)

    # One to many relationship with Fault class
    faults = relationship("Fault", back_populates="faultmap", lazy="selectin")


class CM(CustomModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "cm"

    cm_id = Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True)
    status = Column("status", String(32), nullable=False)
    created_by = Column("created_by", String(64), default="")
    updated_by = Column("updated_by", String(64), default="")


    # One to many relationship with Fault class
    faults = relationship(
        "Fault",
        back_populates="cm",
        lazy="selectin",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )


class Fault(CustomModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "fault"

    id = Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True)
    cm_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("cm.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        index=True,
    )
    check_id = Column(
        String(96),
        ForeignKey("faultmap.check_id", onupdate="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False,
    )
    jira_ticket = Column("jira_ticket", String(64), default="")
    cm = relationship("CM", back_populates="faults", lazy="selectin")
    faultmap = relationship("NewFaultMap", back_populates="faults", lazy="selectin")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by applying the `unique()` to the resultset which de-duplicates the results on the python side.

Ref: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10157